# Cannot export local databases using phpmyadmin

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, export, magento2

Environment:

Windows 10

XAMPP Win32 7.0.23

PHP: 7.0.23

MariaDB 10.1.28?

Magento 2.1.9

I cannot export any databases. I get that "Warning: a form on this page has more than 1000 fields" message, and then the export does not work. From what I've read, you're supposed to change the max_input_vars in php.ini. I checked my only php.ini file. The line was commented out. I removed the semicolon and increased the value - a few times. Here is what it looks like now:

; How many GET/POST/COOKIE input variables may be accepted

max_input_vars = 10000

No matter what I increased it to, I still get the same 1,000 fields message when I try to export a database. I searched the entire XAMPP directory and sub-directories, but found no other php.ini except for the one in the xampp/php directory. I would not think it needs to be higher than 10,000 for a fairly new Magento database with only a few products in it. When I imported the database into XAMPP, it was less than 2 MB in total size. I tried exporting another Magento database for the unmodified demo site, and I get the same warning and result.

Can someone help me? Thanks.

UPDATE:
info.php created and verifies the current max_input_vars = 10000. I am selecting the database in phpmyadmin, and then clicking on the export button at the top. The export, in simple mode, selects all tables for the given database for export.

Answer (score 0):

put info.php into document root with

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

call the file in browser and check the value for max_input_vars.

Also specify if you are exporting a whole database or a query result for further advice

Comment: info.php created and verifies the current max_input_vars = 10000. I am selecting the database in phpmyadmin, and then clicking on the export button at the top. The export, in simple mode, selects all tables for the given database for export.